# jQuery Colorbox document overflow:visible not applying

Tags: jquery, css, overflow, colorbox

I have a page which uses the jQuery Colorbox plugin. My JS for the page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).bind('cbox_open', function() {
        $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
    });
    $(document).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
        $("html").css("overflow", "visible");
    });

        $(".iframe").colorbox({innerWidth:780, innerHeight:"90%", iframe:true});
     });
</script>
```

The intent of the first two code pieces is to disable the vertical scroll bar on the parent page behind the colorbox when open. This works without issue. Additionally, when the colorbox is closed, the vertical bars should re-appear. The latter works in all browsers **except** IE 7.

I know it reaches the code without any errors in code for two reasons:

1 - testing an alert works within "$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function() {"

2 - it works in every other browser and version of IE 8+.

I have changed the overflow value to "scroll" but this adds an unnecessary horizontal scroll to the page as well which is undesired.

Is there a different way to make overflow or vertical scroll appear in ie7 than listed?

Comment: note: overflow:auto seems to work - I am curious however why :visible would not work in this case if anybody can explain. Is this a bug in IE7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, this won't work in ie7 on the html or body elements. I recommend wrapping your entire document in a `<div>` and setting it to `height:100%` and `width:100%` and controlling overflow with that div instead. Additionally, (and this may be a matter of taste) you should be using `removeAttr('style')` on the element to return its state rather than changing the css to `overflow:visible`.

As a side note, this method resolves the issue for iPad as well, which suffers from the same scrolling problem as ie7

Comment: why set in a div if this is all you are trying to achieve? Just set the html or body tags to the css style elements you mention with the CSS. Also - curious why you prefer the removeAttr method (this assumes I have a style defined which I currently don't).

Comment: The reason is that ie7 and mobile devices are not obedient when it comes too `html` and `body` tags. It should work, but so far it just hasn't for me atleast, while this method has worked 100% of the time.

Comment: `$("html").css("overflow", "hidden");` command uses the style attribute, so using `removeAttr` will unto that command in a truer sense than setting the css a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Of note:

```
overflow:auto
```

seems to do the trick, though not sure why the :visible property would not apply in this case (as it works in every other browser). What is it about IE7 that causes this to mess up?